# JPA Specifications query returning simple findAll result without conditions

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity Classes:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "INTERNAL_USER")
public class InternalUserEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "MIDDLE_NAME")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "LOCATION")
    private String location;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME", referencedColumnName = "USERNAME")
    private UserEntity userEntity;
}
```

```
import com.metrica.signite.model.UserStatus;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Table(name = "USER")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "ROLES")
    private String roles;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
    private String phoneNumber;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "USER_STATUS")
    private UserStatus userStatus;
}
```

```
import com.yyy.xxx.entity.InternalUserEntity;
import com.yyy.xxx.entity.UserEntity;
import com.yyy.xxx.model.Role;
import com.yyy.xxx.model.UserStatus;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import javax.persistence.criteria.Join;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class InternalUserSpecifications {

    public static Specification<InternalUserEntity> filterByNameStartsWith(String columnName, String value) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            String likePattern =  value + "%";
            return criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(columnName), likePattern);
        };
    }

    public static Specification<InternalUserEntity> filterByRoles(String value) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Join<UserEntity, InternalUserEntity> userEntityInInternalUser = root.join("userEntity");
            String likePattern = "%" + value + "%";
            return criteriaBuilder.like(userEntityInInternalUser.get("roles"), likePattern);
        };
    }

    public static Specification<InternalUserEntity> filterByColumnEqualsInUserEntity(String columnName, String value) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Join<UserEntity, InternalUserEntity> userEntityInInternalUser = root.join("userEntity");
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(userEntityInInternalUser.get(columnName), value);
        };
    }

    public static Specification<InternalUserEntity> internalUserSearchSpecs(UserStatus userStatus, List<Role> roles, String name) {
        Specification<InternalUserEntity> spec = Specification.where(null);
        if(StringUtils.hasText(name)) {
            List<String> namesLst = Arrays.stream(name.split(AppConstants.SINGLE_SPACE))
                    .filter(n -> !n.equals(AppConstants.EMPTY_STRING))
                    .toList();

            String name1;
            String lastName;
            if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(namesLst)) {
                if(namesLst.size() == 1) {
                    name1 = namesLst.get(0);
                    spec.and(filterByNameStartsWith("firstName", name1)).or(filterByNameStartsWith("lastName", name1));
                } else {
                    name1 = namesLst.get(0);
                    lastName = namesLst.get(1);
                    spec.and(filterByNameStartsWith("fistName", name1)).and(filterByNameStartsWith("lastName", lastName));
                }
            }
        }
        if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(roles)) {
            roles.stream().map(Role::toString).forEach(role -> {
                spec.and(filterByRoles(role));
            });
        }
        if(null != userStatus) {
            spec.and(filterByColumnEqualsInUserEntity("userStatus", userStatus.toString()));
        }
        return spec;
    }
}
```

```
import com.yyy.xxx.entity.InternalUserEntity;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface InternalUserRepository extends JpaRepository<InternalUserEntity, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<InternalUserEntity> {
}
```

The service class method has the following:

```
Specification<InternalUserEntity> searchSpecs = InternalUserSpecifications.internalUserSearchSpecs(userStatus, roles, name);
        Page<InternalUserEntity> page = internalUserRepository.findAll(searchSpecs, PageRequest.of(pageNo, size));
```

When I run the application, there are two queries being printed. One is the select all query on INTERNAL_USER table, and the other is a SELECT * query on USER table where username = (username from internal user table).

There is no join query or conditions executed. Basically the Specificaitons is not working. The result I am getting is that of a findAll without any conditions.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50750914/1915448. The issue is that the `Specification` is immutable, so if you do `spec.and()`, it returns a new `Specification`, but you do nothing with that new specification. So the net result is that you're basically using `Specifications.where(null)`.